# Adding an MVC Constraint still calls Controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to add a `constraint` to a `controller`.  I may have this completely wrong, but my understanding is that if the `route` doesn't match, then it *shouldn't* call the `constructor` method?

Here is my route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UserProfile",
    "UserProfile/{userName}",
    new { controller = "UserProfile", action = "Index" },
    new { userName = @"[a-zA-Z]+" }
);
```

So, I thought that because I'm asking for a `userName`, when I hit the url `mywebsite/UserProfile` it shouldn't match?  Please can some correct me on my thinking, also if someone can help with regards to getting a `route` *not* call the `constructor` method because the `userName` is missing that would be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only this route registered then the controller won't be instantiated or hit by this route. I assume that the behavior you are observing is due to the fact that you also have left the default route registration which will match a request `/UserProfile` to the `UserProfile` controller and the `Index` action:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So remove this default route and you should be OK. Your route definition should look like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "UserProfile",
        "UserProfile/{userName}",
        new { controller = "UserProfile", action = "Index" },
        new { userName = @"[a-zA-Z]+" }
    );
}
```

Comment: Using Phil Haacks route debugger, it fails when I remove the `Default` route.  I get a `NO MATCH` from the output of the Route Debugger, even when I specify a `userName`

Comment: @Neil Knight, is your controller called `UserProfileController` or only `UserProfile` and does it contain an `Index` action?

Comment: It is called `UserProfileController` and does contain an `Index` action.  The problem appears to be with the regular expression.  When I change the `+` for `.*` it works.

Comment: @Neil Knight, because of your regular expression if you request `/UserProfile` the controller will not be hit. If you request `/UserProfile/abc`, the Index action should be hit and passed a parameter userName=abc. You could use only A-Z letters in the username. No numbers, ... Adapt your regex if necessary.